# In R Markdown in RStudio, code chunks after a four-backtick-block loses interactivity (e.g., "Run Current Chunk" button disappears)

Tags: r-markdown

I followed Xie Yihui's [tip](https://yihui.org/en/2017/11/knitr-verbatim-code-chunk/) to render a code chunk as verbatim in the output of a `R Markdown` document. While the result looks fine, I notice that the formatting and interactivity on the RStudio interface changes, that is, code chunks after a four-backtick block are no longer displayed with buttons such as "Run Current Chunk" at the top right. The `R Markdown` is inserted below.

How can I keep using the four-backtick trick (or use another trick with the same effect) while maintaining the interactivity of the interface?

`````
---
title: "Diamond sizes"
date: '2016-08-25'
output:
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: default
  html_document: default
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
```

To show a verbatim R code chunk following Xie Yihui's trick ([link](https://yihui.org/en/2017/11/knitr-verbatim-code-chunk/)):

````
`r ''````{r}
library(gapminder)

gapminder %>% ggplot(aes(year, lifeExp, group = country)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 1/3)
```
````

```{r}
library(gapminder)

gapminder %>% ggplot(aes(year, lifeExp, group = country)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 1/3)
```
`````

Screenshot of RStudio where the 1st code chunk displays as expected but the 2nd one doesn't come with the execution/setting buttons:
[image: screenshot of RStudio where the 1st code chunk displays as expected but the 2nd one doesn't come with the execution/setting buttons]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add one last triple backticks at the end. I do see though however it does add the 3 additional tickmarks to the rendered document, but this is what I did you atleast get the other chunk mark

[image]

updated code 8/21/2021

`````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Daniel"
date: "8/21/2021"
output: html_document
---
```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
```

To show a verbatim R code chunk following Xie Yihui's trick     ([link](https://yihui.org/en/2017/11/knitr-verbatim-code-chunk/)):

````
`r ''````{r}
library(gapminder)

gapminder %>% ggplot(aes(year, lifeExp, group = country)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 1/3)
```
````


```{r}
library(gapminder)

gapminder %>% ggplot(aes(year, lifeExp, group = country)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 1/3)
```
`````